# Why is a table with width of 75% wider than three tables which total 99%?

Tags: html, width, html-table, spacebars

I have three HTMLTables on a page, where the second is to the right of the first, and the third is to the right of the second:

HTMLTable1 (width="33%") + HTMLTable2 (width="33%") + HTMLTable3 (width="33%")

I have a table below them with width of 75:

HTMLTable (width="75%")                                                 |

As you can see here:

[image]

...the single table is wider than the other three.

Why is the "75" wider than the "99", and how can I get it to take up less width?

### UPDATE

Based on IBJ's fiddle, I used the following on the top three tables (tblTravelerInfo, tblTopMiddle, and tblTopRight):

```
<table class="toptables">
```

...and the following on the table below (tblExpenseDescription):

```
<table class="middletable" border="1">
```

...with this CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.toptables{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1px;
    border: 0;
}
.middletable{
    width:75%;
    float:left;
}
```

...with this SpaceBars:

```
<div class="container">
{{> tblTravelerInfo}}
{{> tblTopMiddle}}
{{> tblTopRight}}
{{> tblExpenseDescription}}
</div>
```

...and it only got slightly better - the bottom table is a little less wide than the top three...???

Comment: There's a couple things that can force a table to be wider than what it's told to be. Also are all the widths always relative to the document body? We'd need to see some code.

Comment: Because table usually fit to their content. You can try use `table-layout:fixed`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width by percentage is based on the container the tag is located inside.
SO if those containers are different then the percentages would be different.

I'm not sure how you have your HTML structured but something like this will give you your desired results.

CSS

```
.container{
    width:100%;
}

.box{
    width:33%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:1px;
}
.bottombox{
    width:75%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

JSFIDDLE link
https://jsfiddle.net/2qu9edb0/

Answer (score 1):

You should set the with of container of upper tables to 100%.